# Google Oauth2 Application Type Web server vs Desktop App?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to create a web app for my server which can connect my website forms to Google Sheet. While generating the OAuth client ID and Secret I chose "webserver" and I needed to enter a call-back URI to handle the authorization code returned back from Google as a response.

[image]

Well, now I created another client id, but this time I chose Application type as "Desktop" and I didn't need to enter any redirect URI. In my PHP app, I used redirect URI as `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`.

[image]

However, in both cases, I was able to get Access Token and Refresh Token and my Google Sheet API working smoothly.

So my question why I should choose Application Type as "Webserver" and do an extra step by entering "Redirect URI"? What is the benefit of doing so?

You may check a Quickstart Oauthflow here https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php#step_1_turn_on_the

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question why I should choose Application Type as "Webserver" and do an extra step by entering "Redirect URI"? What is the benefit of doing so?

Security.   Web server client will return the auth to your server.  Installed will return it to where ever the request came from.  If someone got your client id and secret for a web app they couldn't use it.  However if someone got your client id and secret for an installed app they could easily use it to impersonate your developer account.

## What is client id and client secret.

Think of the Client id as a login and the secret as its password.  This login and password identify your project to Google and they identify the developer of that project as you.

You the developer are responsible for this login and password.  If it is stolen then as far as google can see it is your application using it google has no way of knowing other wise.   If the login and password for a desktop app is stolen someone could put up an app and as far as anyone would know it would appear to be your app.

You create super awesome email app which gives access to a users gmail account.  It becomes very popular and a lot of people know the name.   Someone steals your client id and secret creates an app that looks exactly like your super awesome email app.  There is no way for anyone to know its not.  Because its set up as a desktop app this person could then put it up and start harvesting authorization from your potentiate users without them having any idea.  It looks exactly like your app only the responses are going to urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob which is the host server of the person who put up this app to mimic yours.

Unless your application is running on a users machine its really not a good idea to use installed credentials.  That being said theirs nothing to stop you from doing so it will work.

Comment: You mean, if I set the `Desktop App`, any number of servers installed on that desktop can impersonate my account. Is it?

Comment: I mean if you set it to desktop app.  And someone steals your client id and client secret some how.   They can then use that to create an app that as far as google can tell is you as far as the users who login its you.   This evil person could then spam the API so much that Google locks you down for spamming and there will be no way for you to access your account until the end of time.  Also user data will have been stolen on  your behalf which may put you liable for legal reasons.